# Ruby on Rails: iterating through array with specific index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

How do I iterate through an array if I have the specific index?

```
@lv = {'apple' => ['round', 'red'], 'name' => ['tags', 'more tags']}

if params[:value]
    @lv.each do |key, tags|
        if params[:value] == key
            tags.each_with_index do |tag, index|
                ... should display round and red?
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I have an array `@lv` and I want to be able to get the values if there's a parameter associated with it. example:

`someURL.com/?value=0`
Then this is supposed to get the key `apple`. I want to get the values from `apple` which should be `round` and `red`. My logic in the above codes is wrong, but I'm trying to figure out what is the syntax to call out the correct key to iterate?

Comment: This makes no sense; `@lv` is a map, not an array. Using numeric indices on a map is strange.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm new to rails, and it just seems to be working when I use it as a variable or some sort, is it better to just take the @ out?

Comment: Whether it's an instance or local variable is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Hi Andrew, please tell me what you are trying to achieve and I can suggest an alternate solution. How are you generating @lv, and why... and why are you passing an index in the URL rather than the actual desired key (ie. apple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense; `@lv` is a map, not an array. Using numeric indices on a map is strange.

You *can* rely on insertion order in Ruby 1.9+, so `@lv[@lv.keys[params[:value].to_i]]` would actually retrieve what you want, but IMO it's semantically sketchy.

```
@lv[@lv.keys[params[:value].to_i]].each_with_index do |tag, index|
  ...
end
```

I'd also recommend using at least one intermediate variable to clean up that expression.

Comment: would be able to give an alternative example?

Comment: @andrewliu Doing it "right" depends on what you're actually doing, and why, which I don't know.

Comment: Can you explain what your code does? I'm sorry, I'm really new to Ruby on Rails

Comment: @andrewliu Break it down expression by expression: it uses the integer value of the parameter as an array index into the keys of the hash to get a key, then uses that key to get a value from the hash, then iterates over the hash value, assumed to be an array.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a lot of effort to make it work this way.  Why not change the view so you can select the key name:

`http://example.com/?value=apple` instead of `http://example.com?value=0`

then you can change your controller code to:

```
@tags = @lv[params['value']]
```

Then just iterate through `@tags` in your view, or whatever else you're trying to do with the list of tags.

Comment: I tried testing `puts @lv[params['apple']]` but doesn't come out anything nor did `puts @lv[params[0]]`. What is the correct syntax to getting something similar to `params[0]`? I'd like to output the value based on the index. So if I want to get values from apple, I would need to pass `0` in somewhere. How do I do that?